# How to get multiple values from a singe query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT NUM,
       PARAM_1 
FROM STOCK_CARD_PARAMETER WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE FK_STOCK_CARD IN (SELECT FK_sTOCK_CARD 
                        FROM STOCK_BARCODE WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        WHERE BARCODE = '2002002232364' )
```

And it returns:

```
 NUM     PARAM_1
 1       İNDİRİMSİZ
 2       SEZON
 3       UNISEXYETISKIN
```

I have to get a result like that. (side by side)

```
İNDİRİMSİZ  SEZON UNISEXYETISKIN
```

To do this, I execute almost the same query 2 times like this:

```
INDIRIM = (SELECT PARAM_1 
           FROM STOCK_CARD_PARAMETER WITH(NOLOCK) 
           WHERE FK_STOCK_CARD IN (SELECT FK_sTOCK_CARD 
                                   FROM STOCK_BARCODE WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                   WHERE BARCODE = @BARKOD  AND NUM = 1)),
STATU = ( SELECT PARAM_1 
          FROM STOCK_CARD_PARAMETER WITH(NOLOCK) 
          WHERE  FK_STOCK_CARD IN (SELECT FK_sTOCK_CARD 
                                   FROM STOCK_BARCODE WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                   WHERE BARCODE = @BARKOD AND NUM = 2))
```

`NUM` column is the key here. How do I make this two query combined and get the result side by side?

Comment: Results format on one line is ok for your example, but what happens then it returns several thousand "rows"?  String them out in a single line?  The display is at the mercy of those who put data into the tables. Who, being humans, will do unexpected things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `PIVOT`

```
SELECT  [1], [2], [3]
FROM
(SELECT NUM, PARAM_1 
    FROM table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(PARAM_1)
FOR NUM IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

---

Sample data with output

```
WITH C(NUM, PARAM_1) AS(
    SELECT 1 ,  N'İNDİRİMSİZ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ,  N'SEZON' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ,  N'UNISEXYETISKIN'
)

SELECT  [1], [2], [3]
FROM
(SELECT NUM, PARAM_1 
    FROM C) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(PARAM_1)
FOR NUM IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Output

```
İNDİRİMSİZ  SEZON   UNISEXYETISKIN
```